# Consumer does not receive messages after kafka producer/consumer restart

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

We have one producer & one consumer & one partition. Both consumer/producer are spring boot applications. The consumer app runs on my local machine while producer along with kafka & zookeeper on a remote machine.

During development, I redeployed my producer application with some changes. But after that my consumer is not receiving any messages. I tried restarting the consumer, but no luck. What can be the issue and/or how can it be solved?

**Consumer Config:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: sales
          content-type: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${SERVICE_REGISTRY_HOST:127.0.0.1}
          zkNodes: ${SERVICE_REGISTRY_HOST:127.0.0.1}
          defaultZkPort: 2181
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
server:
  port: 0
```

**Producer Config**:

```
cloud:
stream:
  defaultBinder: kafka
  bindings:
    output:
      destination: sales
      content-type: application/json
  kafka:
    binder:
      brokers: ${SERVICE_REGISTRY_HOST:127.0.0.1}
      zkNodes: ${SERVICE_REGISTRY_HOST:127.0.0.1}
      defaultZkPort: 2181
      defaultBrokerPort: 9092
```

**EDIT2**:

After 5 minutes the consumer app dies with following exception:

```
2017-09-12 18:14:47,254 ERROR main o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner:253 - Cannot initialize Binder
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
2017-09-12 18:14:47,255  WARN main o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:550 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Cannot initialize binder:
2017-09-12 18:14:47,256  INFO main o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter:449 - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-09-12 18:14:47,257  INFO main o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter:241 - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2017-09-12 18:14:47,257  INFO main o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter:375 - Summary on shutdown: input
2017-09-12 18:14:47,257  INFO main o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter:375 - Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
2017-09-12 18:14:47,258  INFO main o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter:375 - Summary on shutdown: errorChannel
```

Comment: Sounds like pretty simple scenario. Would you mind to share that application somewhere on GitHub so we will be able to reproduce the problem locally?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I am sorry but I can't share my code. What details do u need to suggest a solution?

Comment: I have no ideas without code. Maybe you can share configs for consumer and producer? And yes, I know that you can't share the whole application, but may be, at least, can come up with some simple Spring Boot app for us...

Comment: @ArtemBilan added configs.

Comment: Good. Thank you! So, well. What is the Kafka Binder version? What do you mean with the "redeployed"? How to do that locally? The SCSt app is a Microservice. I'm confused.

Comment: Turning on DEBUG logging is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like there is already a [bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/67) reported with `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` stating the `resetOffset` property has no effect. Hence, on the consumer always requested messages with the offset as `latest`.

As mentioned on the git issue, the only workaround is to fix this via the kafka consumer CLI tool.

Answer (score 1):

See if the suggestion above about DEBUG reveals any further information. It looks like you are getting some Timeout exception from the KafkaTopicProvisioner. But that occurs when you restart the consumer I assume. It looks like the consumer has some trouble communicating to the broker somehow and you need to find out whats going on there.